# I accidentally removed the Bandpage connection permission from my Soundcloud settings. How do I undo this?

Tags: soundcloud

My bandpage still works - I just can't add any new songs from soundcloud.

I am here - http://soundcloud.com/settings/connections - and need to connect bandpage to "Connected applications"

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

if you hover over your username in the top right a menu will pop down. Click settings, then soundcloud. Then click disconnect soundcloud (if it says you can disconnect). This will reload the page. Then go back through the same process but connect this time. This will reset the link between the apps.